# Session Data ist empty after redirect with SSO

Tags: php, session

I'm building something and my Session is not working properly

The routine is simple
Page 1: LOGIN with one button that calls
Page 2: Get User Name and stuff from SimpleSAML and save that in the SESSION and redirect to
Page 3: Where to user is supossed to do stuff

Code Page 1:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <title>Projectname</title>  
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/index_style.css" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="style/favicons/icons8-universe-dotted-96.png">
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div class="container">  
            <form name="f1" action = "dev_sso_auth.php" method = "POST">
                <h1>Projectname</h1>
                <input type="Submit" id = "btn" value = "SSO LOGIN &#x1f510;" class="login"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code Page 2:

```
<?php
session_start();
/*SSO Login mit return eines Arrays*/
require_once('/var/simplesamlphp/src/_autoload.php');
$as = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('default-sp');
$as->requireAuth();
$attributes = $as->getAttributes();


/*Displayname auslesen*/
$displayName = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname';
$attrs = $as->getAttributes();
if (!isset($attributes[$displayName][0])) {
    throw new Exception('displayName attribute missing.');
}
$val_displayname = $attributes[$displayName][0];


/*Givenname auslesen*/
$givenName = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname';
$attrs = $as->getAttributes();
if (!isset($attributes[$givenName][0])) {
    throw new Exception('givenName attribute missing.');
}
$val_givenName = $attributes[$givenName][0];


/*Surname auslesen*/
$surName = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname';
$attrs = $as->getAttributes();
if (!isset($attributes[$surName][0])) {
    throw new Exception('surName attribute missing.');
}
$val_surName = $attributes[$surName][0];


/*Emailadress auslesen*/
$emailAdress = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress';
$attrs = $as->getAttributes();
if (!isset($attributes[$emailAdress ][0])) {
    throw new Exception('emailAdress attribute missing.');
}
$val_emailAdress = $attributes[$emailAdress][0];

$user_givenName = $_POST[$val_givenName];
$_SESSION["user_displayName"] = $val_displayname;
$_SESSION["user_givenName"] = $val_givenName;
$_SESSION["user_surName"] = $val_surName;
$_SESSION["user_emailAdress"] = $val_emailAdress;


// Verbindung zur Datenbank aufbauen
//Just editet the stuff inside the connection for posting it online
$conn = new mysqli('DATABASE', 'USER', 'PASS', 'TABLE');

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// SQL-Abfrage ausführen
$sql = "SELECT R.role FROM TABLE U JOIN User_Roles UR ON U.user_id = UR.user_id JOIN Roles R ON UR.role_id = R.role_id WHERE U.mailadress ='$val_emailAdress'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Ergebnis in ein Array speichern
$userRoles = array();
array_push($userRoles, "GUEST");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $userRoles[] = $row['role'];
}

// Verbindung schließen
$conn->close();
$_SESSION['userRoles'] = $userRoles; //Speichern aller dem eingeloggten Benutzers zugewiesesn Rollen in der Session als Array
/*echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<hr>';
echo $_SESSION["user_givenName"];
*/
header('Location: dashboards/dev_dashboard.php');
exit;
?>
```

Note for the Code in Page 2:
Everything works like i wanted to

- I can get the Userstuff from SSO in this way, because the array is shapped differently on other clients, but in this way it works
- I insert the stuff in an array in the session
- The `var_dump($_SESSION);` works
- The `echo $_SESSION["user_givenName"];` works

Code Page 3:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  print_r($_SESSION);

  echo '<pre>';
  var_dump($_SESSION);
  echo '</pre>';
  
  echo '<hr>';
  echo $_SESSION["user_givenName"];
?>
```

Note Code Page 3:
i only see an empty array

Where is my error?

i followed this tutorial
https://www.php-einfach.de/php-tutorial/php-sessions/#Laengeres_Beispielscript_mit_Sessions

and this works perfectly, so i assume my settings from the server are right.

I expect when i save something in the `$_SESSION` and then redirect to the next page the data inside the `$_SESSION` shouldn't be lost.

I guess there is something wrong in my code.
At first i would be happy for a working solution and afterwards feedback for my code.
Sorry I'm a beginner, as you can see.
Be gently

Comment: Your page 2 will get redirected to `dashboards/dev_dashboard.php`, make sure this php script also has `session_start();` at the top

Comment: @KenLee my page 3 is the dashboards/dev_dashboard.php and there’s on top the session_start(). I don’t get it why it’s not working.

Comment: When you're on page 3, do you see the same PHPSESSID cookie as page 2?

Comment: Good point @Barmar I didn’t try that, I will try that later, I will first check the PHPSESSID Manual again.

Comment: @Barmar I checked the manual ant tried different approaches with cleanup, regenerate the session id, unset the session and destroy the session and pass the values to a new session, but it still won’t work. I know it isn’t a good approach, but I will try to store everything in a cookie, redirect to the next page, then store the data from the cookie in the new session and afterwards destroy this cookie. I would be really happy if some kind person could give me a hint or point where my problem is.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this documentation](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/2.1/simplesamlphp-sp-api.html):

> Note on PHP sessions and SimpleSAMLphp API calls : Some SimpleSAMLphp
> calls replace the current active PHP session. If you previously
> started a session and wish to write to it, then you must cleanup the
> SimpleSAMLphp session before you can write to your session. If you do
> not need to modify your own session, then you can leave the cleanup
> call out; however, forgetting to call cleanup is a common source of
> hard to find bugs.

Comment: @MickaelKre I also thought of a feature inside the SSO that destroys my session, but in the end of my page 2 there is only stored in the session like I wanted to be there. I guess when I can print the stuff from the session at the end of file 2 I should also have access to it in site 3.

Comment: yes you're right this is a problem with the SimpleSaml Session data, i found it with echoing the session id on site 2 and 3. Thats the reason, why i cant see the session data on the next page. I've tried now different approches with cleanup, regenerate_session_id and sesseion_destroy and afterwards starting a new session, where I'm putting the data inside. Do you or anyone can give me a hint how to do it properly, i dont get it.

Comment: I just used as workaround to store every data I parsed in a cookie then redirect to the next script where I started a definitely new session , store the data from the cookie in the session destroy all cookies and then redirect to my real next usable page. I know there should be a way better solution, but honestly I don’t get it and would really appreciate help there